# Transform and webkit animation in CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a JS script that automticly resize an image and also a CSS3 animation for BounceIn effect. They work well separately but not together .. How can I combine the two effects ? Here's the HTML/JS Code

```
 </head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid perso" id="container">
  <center>
    <img class="img-responsive row" src="../img/row.png">
  </center>
  <img class="img-responsive button1 bounceIn" id="button1" src="../img/button.png">
</div>


<script>


    var $el = $("#button1");
    var $container=$("#container");

    var elHeight = $el.outerHeight();
    var elWidth = $el.outerWidth();

    var wHeight1 = $container.height();
    var wWidth1 = $container.width();

    ratioHeight=elHeight/wHeight1;
    ratioWitdh=elWidth/wWidth1;

    $(window).resize(function () {

    var scale;

    var wHeight2 = $container.height();
    var wWidth2 = $container.width();

    var elHeight2=ratioHeight*wHeight2;
    var elWidth2=ratioWitdh*wWidth2;


      scale = (elHeight/elWidth)/(elHeight2/elWidth2);

      $el.css({
        transform: "scale(" + scale + ")"
      });

    });


</script>
```

And here's the CSS code :

```
.img-responsive.button1.bounceIn
{
    position:absolute; 
    left:75%; 
    top:50%;

    transform: scale(1);

    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
    animation-duration: .75s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;

}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It remains kinda unclear to me what the "combined effect" should look like.

Comment: The JS resize the picture in regard of the container size --> triggered with an event   And the CSS is only at the beginning a BounceIn effect

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the effect, i have copyed the code to a jsfiddle but it doesn't works, is it possible to see what is your point of view specially for this two lines of code

```
var $el = $("#button1");
var $container=$("#container");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2eyctrpm/